# How to enable text box on check box check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to enable and disable of text box when check box checked.
But here only one text box enabled when the check box checked.
How to enable and disable two text box when check box checked ?
Here is my code:

```
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input_control').change(function () {
        $('input[name=' + this.value + ']')[0].disabled = !this.checked;
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` will only return you single DOM element, thus it working for single element.

Since you need to modify value of multiple element, You should use [`.prop( propertyName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) method

> Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.

```
$('input[name=' + this.value + ']').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[name=' + this.value + ']')[0].prop( "disabled", !this.checked);
```

EDIT:

```
 $('input[name=' + this.value + ']').first().prop( "disabled", !this.checked);
 $('input[name=' + this.value + ']').prop( "disabled", !this.checked);
```

Comment: The state will generate error as `[0]` will return underlying DOM element and they don't have `.prop()` method. Also code dump is not useful.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!